# Keras model val_accuracy 1.00, and gives wrong output when testing

Tags: tensorflow, keras, model, prediction

I've trained a Kaggle dataset ([this one](https://www.kaggle.com/gti-upm/leapgestrecog/version/1)) to detect hand gestures. when training, it gives the val_accuracy = 1.00, here is an image or you can see it using the
[link to colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1VDNy18UDem5oNkNf9X9ECmje_86OFlmJ?usp=sharing)

[image]

when I try to test the model using an image from the dataset, it gives right predictions, but when I try to use real-world image for "ok" gesture (you can see it in the end of the colab project), it just gives wrong outputs, I've tries other images, it gives also wrong predictions.

any help please?

Answer (score 1):

When you have a real world image you want to predict you must process that image in exactly the same as you processed the training images. For example
image size must be the same
pixels must be scaled the same
if trained on rgb images real world image must be an rgb image
if trained on grayscale real world image must be gray scale

Comment: First of all, Thanks for your answer.
Actually all of that is done in the project.